# Ruby escape ARGV argument or string as argument to shell command

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, scripting

Ok this is driving me crazy:

```
`ls #{"/media/music/Miles Davis"}`
```

fails because of the space between "Miles" and "Davis"

Say I write a ruby script and a user passes file path as an argument. How do I escape it and feed to a shell-out command. Yes, yes, I know, shelling out should be avoided. But this is a contrived example, I still need this.

I would do `system("ls", ARGV[0])`, but it doesn't return the stdout output of ls as a string, which is what backticks do well.

How do escape whatever you insert in a shellout?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `require 'shellwords'` and `Shellwords.escape`, which will fix this sort of stuff for you:

http://apidock.com/ruby/Shellwords/shellescape

Comment: You can also use the shortcut `String#shellescape`, like this: 

`ls #{"/media/music/Miles Davis".shellescape}`

Answer (score 7):

**Stay away from building shell strings**

This is a fine vector for arbitrary code execution.

In this case, you could use `popen`, which does the escaping for you, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
IO.popen(['printf', 'a b']) do |f|
  puts f.read
end
```

This outputs:

```
a b
```

just as if we had run on the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/printf 'a b'
```

If `a b` hadn't been escaped, we wouldn't get `a b` as expected, because running an unquoted:

```
/usr/bin/printf a b
```

in the terminal gives:

```
a/usr/bin/printf: warning: ignoring excess arguments, starting with ‘b’
```

Tested in Ubuntu 20.02, Ruby 2.6.

Comment: This should have more upvotes. popen also allows to print out a streamed response rather conveniently eg. while (line = f.gets) { puts line }.

Comment: Here's an even more compact version: `IO.popen(["file", "--brief", "--mime-type", untrustworthy_input], in: :close, err: :close).read`

Comment: @V-R: ah OK, I understood the edit. I'll just use this double space version for now so that users don't have to learn about `%q`, but the edit was good.

Answer (score -2):

Double quotes also works:

```
`ls "#{'/media/music/Miles Davis'}"`
```

or

```
`ls "#{ARGV[0]}"`
```

Comment: Don't do that. Consider:

`a = '-l" | wc -l #"';`

``ls "#{a}"``

Comment: This works for spaces, but fails of your string has a `"`, `$`, or several other characters.