# ruby - weird duplication with backtick in gsub

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to backslash-escape a filename that has backticks in it, to pass to some shell commands. I am seeing some weird behavior when trying to use gsub for this.

Some examples in IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> 'weird`things'.gsub('`', '\`')
=> "weirdweirdthings"
irb(main):002:0> 'weird`things'.gsub('`', '\\`')
=> "weirdweirdthings"
irb(main):003:0> 'weird`things'.gsub('`', '\\\`')
=> "weird\\`things"    # this is what I want
irb(main):004:0> 'weird`things'.gsub('`', '\\\\`')
=> "weird\\`things"
irb(main):005:0> 'weird`things'.gsub('`', '\\\\\`')
=> "weird\\weirdthings"
```

What is going on here? Does this have something to do with the $` global variable?

Comment: Also you might want to check out `Shellwords.escape`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921599/ruby-escape-argv-argument-or-string-as-argument-to-shell-command/6922339

Comment: Thanks @Casper, that's just what I needed!

Comment: Or even better, don't build command lines as strings, use the multi-argument version of [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-system) or [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) and avoid the shell entirely.